# What to write as 'purpose of journey' when visiting the Schengen area for a summer school?

Tags: visas, schengen, study

I'm going to participate in a Summer School in Management for two weeks.

When applying for Schengen visa, should I put the main purpose of the journey as Study or Tourism/cultural because the period is short?

Comment: How does the shortness of the period affect the purpose of the trip?

Comment: How serious do you intend to take the summer school? If you intend to skip classes and make a cultural journey around Europe or sit at the beach the whole day long, check "tourism/cultural". If you intend to attend most classes, check "education".

Answer (score 4):

I would answer the question honestly. Instances of dishonestly on a visa application will hurt your credibility and cause the officers to wonder what else you aren't telling them. The primary purpose of your trip appears to be to take a class. Therefore you are traveling to study, even if only for a short period of time.

In your application, you can explain the nature and duration of the class.